# How can I display different data (the data chosen by user) on a page for different authenticated users on ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I am trying to build a website with Reactjs where user can log in and can save their favorite ads and I want to display those saved ads on a different page. How can I display different data on that page for every user? I used google firebase for authentication.

Comment: Hey there! Have you considered using a global store like redux? Alternatively, you can use React's built in context API, which will provide data to all the components in your tree.

Comment: Hey. Yes, but my question was little different. Let's say there is user A and user B. When user A is logged in, I want to display user A's favorite ads. When use B is logged in, I want to display user B's favorites. When I use basic context or redux, everyone sees common favorites page.

Comment: Ah I understand, you'll need to use a backend database to store their preferences and ads. When a user logs in, you then pull their ads from the database and show it to them. If you're using firebase, you can use firestore or firebase (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database)